# Making a generic jQuery "addListener"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to reproduce Google Maps' `addListener` except with jQuery listeners for clicks, keypresses, etc.

In Moogle Maps, you can write `.event.addListener(map, 'click', function()...` or replace 'click' with 'drag', 'mouseover', etc. For jQuery, I see a parallel with 'click', 'keypress', etc.

I'm stuck at the point where you could maybe pass the trigger type as a variable. It was straightforward to declare individual wrapper listeners, like

```
  function addClickListener(id, fn) {
    $(id).click(function() { fn(event); });
  }      

  // and

  function addKeyPressListener(id, fn) {
    $(id).keypress(function() { fn(event); });
  }
```

What I am looking for is broken, shown below. I can't figure out how Google passes a String like 'click' and make that call a function. Maybe with `eval`? *shudder*

```
  function addListener(id, type, fn) {
    typeFn = $.type;
    $(id).typeFn(function() { fn(event); });
  }
```

Finally: http://jsfiddle.net/YCVVL/

Comment: Have you looked at [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: It does make my question a pointless exercise :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use '[square bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html)' here:

```
function addListener(id, type, fn) {
    $(id)[type](function() { fn(event); }); //< here
}
```

Or use one of:

```
$(id).on(type, function() { fn(event); });
$(id).bind(type, function() { fn(event); });
```

Comment: WOW, very clever. I wouldn't imagine it could take place of a function name. It is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!